# How to use scanner class in java

Tags: java

I want to convert my names.rtf file which contains (the names of people(`String`) `names.rtf = ("ABHISHEK","ANKIT",........"ASHISH")` )    into single `String[]` name such that `name={"ABHISHEK","ANKIT",......"ASHISH"}`

Following is my code suggest please.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 

 public class FileScan {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;
        String thestring ="";
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/abhishekkumar/Desktop/names1.rtf")));
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                thestring+=(s.nextLine());                  
                thestring+="\n";
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(thestring);
    } 
   }
```

Comment: first of all, you are not inserting names into array, and secondly, what issue are you facing?

Comment: @ Batty Yeah i am inserting string i have taken this code from net .I want from you is that to convert indivisual names (String) into a String[].My names.rtf contain names of 500  people separated  by commas.

Comment: Please show some real content of the file. Are the brackets and quotation marks included? Why do you want an array and not a list?

Comment: Are all 500 names on a single line in the file, and are you sure each name is contained between "" .Post the real file contents ?

Comment: @feuerball my names.txt is https://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt I want to convert it into the String[] of the names.

Comment: @nustafa sabir my names.txt is https://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt I want to convert it into the String[] of the names

Comment: See my answer, I have provided a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, why are you using the scanner class in this way to read file ,with bufferedReader,fileReader etc ? Use :-

```
File file = new File("filename.fileformat");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

A possible solution looking at your file in the comments would be:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Location of file to read
        File file = new File("data.rtf");
        String line="";
        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(line);


            }


          String[] nameArray=line.split(","); 

          for(String s:nameArray){

         System.out.print(s+" "); //parse the array to verify entries

         }

            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```